# I'm having problems with inserting subscribers in my DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

I want to insert data in my DE, but instead of inserting each subscriber inside a line, it's putting all the text on my page on one line, how do I fix this?

The Subscribers that I retrieve in my web page using SSJS-

```
{"Status":"OK","RequestID":"07c484ff-a64b-4633-a5ef-64556b86e905","Results":[{"SubscriberKey":"12345678","Client":null,"ListID":0,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","Status":"Active","PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"ObjectID":null,"CustomerKey":null,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"SubscriberKey":"1234","Client":null,"ListID":0,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","Status":"Active","PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"ObjectID":null,"CustomerKey":null,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}],"HasMoreRows":false}"
```

and what goes to my DE is :

[image]

Follow my code

```
  <script runat="server">
         
            Platform.Load("core", "1");
         
            var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
         
         try {
          var res = api.retrieve("ListSubscriber", 
            ["SubscriberKey"],
            {
                Property: "ListID",
                SimpleOperator: "equals",
                Value: "xxxx"
            }
        ); var aa = Platform.Function.InsertData("AutosDE",["SubscriberKey"],
            [Stringify(res)]); 
             Write(Stringify(res));
          
         } catch(error) {
          Write(Stringify(error));
         }
         
        </script>
```

Comment: Stringify res in your insert. (`[Stringify(res)]`. I think that should resolve it

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but now I have a new problem when I'm going to insert the records in my DE, I just refresh my question